# Picmonkey API get display and save image to email form

Tags: html, api

basically Im using picmonkey's api system to put a button on my site that opens my template file into picmokey from my site to be edited. When the user saves this file I would like the image to be input into a email form on mysite where it can be directly sent to me by email.

Right now I have a test button on my site (the 2nd one) that's half way doing what I need it to Im just unfamiliar with this type of stuff and it's a little bit more advanced for me.

killture.com/picmonkey/

There API documention is here 
picmonkey.com/help/articles/1017782-api-documentation

and the code for the button im using is

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.picmonkey.com/service/" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type="hidden" name="_apikey" value="63fa2a00a6ffc755ea3458a72d4af600"/>
<input type="hidden" name="_import" value="http://killture.com/templates/custompillow17x17-pm.png"/>
<input type="hidden" name="_close_target" value="http://plusdope.com">
<input type="hidden" name="_export" value="http://www.killture.com/picmonkey/testimg">
<input type="hidden" name="_export_agent" value="browser">    
<input type="hidden" name="_export_field" value="photo"> 


<input type="submit" value="Create A Custom Pillow"/>
</form>
```

My issue is after I hit save and it takes me back to my site's test page...the url in the address bar is URL encoded with a temporary file that's hosted on picmonkey with a randomly generated file name.

EXAMPLE: killture.com/picmonkey/testimg/?photo=http%3A%2F%2Ftemp.picmonkey.com%2F1d%2F5dWv7AKCvSJ9YzuP2DsC.jpg

1. Im not sure how to automatically display the image file on that page
2. Not sure how to display the image url on the page

How would I make this possible?

**EDIT:**

So now I created the new button (3rd one down) using the code you gave me I have on my test page http://killture.com/picmonkey

**Button code:**

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.picmonkey.com/service/" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type="hidden" name="_apikey" value="63fa2a00a6ffc755ea3458a72d4af600"/>
<input type="hidden" name="_import" value="http://killture.com/templates/custompillow17x17-pm.png"/>
<input type="hidden" name="_export" value="http://www.killture.com/testmonkey">
<input type="hidden" name="_export_agent" value="server">
<input type="hidden" name="_export_field" value="photo">
<input type="hidden" name="_export_method" value="POST">
<input type="submit" value="Create A Custom Pillow"/>
```

after the user hits save they get directed to the page with my form http://killture.com/testmonkey

**The code on the form page is currently**

```
<form action="/testmonkey#wpcf7-f753-p752-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="753" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="3.3.1" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f753-p752-o1" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpnonce" value="86312bd7c3" />

<p>Your Name (required)<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" size="40" /></span> </p>
<p>Your Email (required)<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="text" name="your-email" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" size="40" /></span> </p>
<p>Subject<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-subject"><input type="text" name="your-subject" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" size="40" /></span> </p>
<p>Your Message<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message"><textarea name="your-message" class="wpcf7-form-control  wpcf7-textarea" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea></span> </p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control  wpcf7-submit" /></p>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></form>
```

so now how do I include the code into the form that will send the image with the form? I'm obviously missing a bit of code in my current form for that aspect of it.

Answer (score 1):

Hey, I'm with PicMonkey. It definitely seems like you're close to getting what you want.

You say you have an email form on your site that will send the image to you. Ok, start by using that URL as the target in the _export field:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="_export" value="http://www.killture.com/picmonkey/YOUR_EMAIL_FORM">
```

Since it's a form, you presumably want the image data posted directly to you so that you can attach it to an email. So change the _export_agent field to "server", and add an _export_method field set to "POST":

```html
<input type="hidden" name="_export_agent" value="server">
<input type="hidden" name="_export_field" value="photo">
<input type="hidden" name="_export_method" value="POST">
```

At that point, when a user presses save, a POST request will be made to your form, with the image data in the "photo" field.

If that isn't enough to get you going, feel free to ask more questions in the comments.

EDIT:

I think you need to rethink your plan a bit. /testmonkey is the form for creating the final email. It's not a good choice for the _export target, because all we can do is post an image to you. We can't post the rest of the email fields.

Here's a rough outline what you need to do:

- add another form, call it /picmonkey_export or something. Use that as
  your _export target
- when processing /picmonkey_export, the output sent back to the
  browser should be HTML that calls your /testmonkey form
- that HTML should contain the image data you receive from us. it will then
  comes back to you when the user submits /testmonkey with the completed email
- consider going back to having us send you a URL to the saved image -
  it's easier to write that into a document and have it sent back to you by the user. You can even email HTML to yourself and use an img tag in it.

Hopefully this gets you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you so much I am having a bit of trouble one i get to the page with my form I am wondering what code my form needs to contain so that the image is passed to it and then sent to my email. I will include it in my quetion.

Comment: I edited my orginal post with my updated codes and question. Id like to thank you for all of your help so far!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you'd replied!

Comment: i actually did a work around with php and got it to display that temporary image with the temporary url picmonkey generated inside of the form and then send the link to the image in the email so now when I get the email I just save it my computer...Seems to work fine not sure how long picmonkey saves these temporary images on their server so I just have to make sure I check and save them right away. Thank you for all your help!!! Your original post actually got me headed in the direction I needed to be in.